# Perl PDL - getting the 80% lowest values in a vector

Tags: perl, percentile, pdl

Is there an elegant PDL function which receives a list of values and returns a list of 80% of the original values which are the lowest?

For example:
If I have a list like so: (9, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 6, 10)

I would like to get (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) after calling this function on the original list (The order of the values does not matter - it does not need to sort the values).

I found PDL::Ufunc::oddpct which can return the 80'th percentile but I would like to get a list of the values up to that percentile. I can do it myself but if there's something out of the box - why not use it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use `pct` to get the 80th percentile figure, combined with the `where` primitive to select everything beneath that value. Using your own data it looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;

my $list = pdl(9, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 6, 10);
print qsort $list->where($list <= $list->pct(80/100));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the "do it yourself" that you don't want to do, but it is so easy.  PDL seems might heavy for this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (9, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 6, 10);

my @slist = sort {$a <=> $b} @list;
my @list80 = @slist[0..int(0.8*@slist)-1];

print "@list80";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not PDL, but likely at least as fast:

[Statistics::CaseResampling's select_kth function](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-CaseResampling/lib/Statistics/CaseResampling.pm#select_kth%28ARRAYREF,_K%29)